# Linear Algebra- Subspace Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

"Is the set of all polynomials over the real numbers of degree exactly 2 a subspace of P∞(R)?"

So apparently the answer to this is 'no'. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because $0$ is not in it?

Comment: Could you not say 0 is the coefficient of each?

Comment: I.e 0 = 0*x^2 + 0*x + 0

Comment: Without considering $0$ (somebody assigns it whatever degree you want), another example is $(x^2+1)+(-x^2+x)$.

Comment: @anon: You *could* say that 0 is the coefficient of each nonconstant term in the zero polynomial, but what would the phrase "degree exactly 2" then mean? Would the zero polynomial have "degree exactly 2" and "degree exactly 3" and "degree exactly 1", etc.? That doesn't seem like it captures the notion of "degree" or "exactly" very well.